# How can i center the bullet to the body text in InDesign?

Tags: adobe-indesign

[image]

as you see at the picture, the bullets look not at the right position as it's not centered the body text!
what can i do to fix that problem?
thanks

Comment: Are you using InDesign's bullet tool or pasting in bullet characters?

Comment: I am using (bulleted list) option!

Answer (score 2):

You can define a Character Style for your Bullet Character which has a baseline shift. (Sorry for german screenshots)

**Bullet and Numbering Options**
[image: Bullet and Numbering Options]

**Character Style Options**
[image: Character Style Options]

Comment: I was going to suggest that this may be an artifact of the font that has been chosen. Or that these character styles were set up prior to Eddie N. editing the document. +1